# How to convert local (est ) column timezone to UTC time zone in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have multi columns in sql in local time zones like EST ,PST , CST and so on . We would like convert all these time zones in UTC time zones considering Day light savings into account and save it to another column.

I tried below query but it converts UTC to local time zone (EST) but I am looking for EST to UTC time zone.

select CONVERT(datetime, SWITCHOFFSET(dateTimeField, DATEPART(TZOFFSET,
dateTimeField AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time')))

Comment: Does your value state what it's offset is? If not, how do you know if that value is observing DST or not (without observing a calendar).

Comment: We have it in this format -- 2020-10-27 01:20:54.0900000 and this is an EST column .

Comment: So, again, how do *you* know that is EST and not ESDT?

Comment: This helps me -- select cast('2017-02-08 09:00:00.000' as datetime) AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time'

Comment: But that makes the value EDT (UTC -04:00). You said it was EST (-05:00).

Comment: No , select cast('2017-04-08 09:00:00.000' as datetime) AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time' -- -04:00
select cast('2017-11-08 09:00:00.000' as datetime) AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time' -- -05:00

Comment: "No"? No what..?

Comment: I have mentioned 2 queries , 1st one returns -4 and 2nd returns -5 .

Comment: Is it that you have multiple columns, each of which has a uniform TZ (e.g. one column that is all CST, a different column that is all EST, etc)? Or one column that has a mix? Either way, sample schema/data would be helpful.

Comment: Yes @Ben Thul . Each column is specific to its timezone.

Answer (score 2):

Based on a comment above, you should be able to use the following example to get what you want.

```
DECLARE @ts DATETIME = GETDATE();

SELECT
    @ts AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time',
    @ts AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC',
    CAST(@ts AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS DATETIME)
```

What I'm showing here is the various steps. In turn:

1. Getting an arbitrary `datetime` value. This could easily be a column from your table.
2. Telling SQL "this datetime is in the PST time zone"
3. Telling SQL "convert this PST time to a UTC time"
4. Casting the resulting UTC time back to a datetime (presumably so it will be able to be inserted back into the table)

To be explicit about "what would this look like if I wanted to convert the data in my table?", it'd look something like this:

```
alter table dbo.yourTable add 
   isConverted bit
   constraint DF_yourTable_isConverted default 0;

update top(1000) dbo.yourTable
set yourColumn = CAST(
      yourColumn AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' 
      AS DATETIME
   ),
   isConverted = 1
where isConverted = 0;
```

Note I've added a column whose purpose is to provide a notion of "has this particular row's column been converted?" so you don't accidentally double convert a given value twice. Once all the data in the table is converted, you can drop the column.